# I am writing a code based on some formulas;but my if statement does not seem to work(line 33)

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

```
W = int(input('Enter weight:'))

b = [1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.0]
AR = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
T = [50.99238, 50.05062, 49.07943, 48.05919, 47.00952, 45.92061, 44.79246, 43.62507,       42.42825, 41.18238, 39.90708, 38.60235, 37.24857, 35.86536, 34.4331, 32.97141, 31.48029, 29.94012, 28.37052, 26.76168, 25.1136]
CL = [1.0]
CD = [0.5]
clmax = 2
n = 0
z = 0
while b[n] < 2.1 :

    while AR[z]< 5.1:
        cl = CL[n]
        cd = CD[z]
        s = ((b[n]*b[n])/AR[z])                                
        V = ((2*W*9.81)/(1.2*s*clmax) ** 0.5)*1.1
        vlof = V/1.41
        Vlof = round(vlof)
        D = 0.5*cd*1.2*Vlof*Vlof*s
        L = 0.5*cl*1.2*Vlof*Vlof*s
        a = (9.81/W)*(T[Vlof]-D-O.O5(W-L))
        Sg = (V*V)/(2*a)
        if Sg <= 30:
            print('IT WILL TAKEOFF')
        else:
            print('It will NOT takeoff')
        t/c = int(input('t/c ratio is:'))
        l = int(input('Taper ratio is:'))
        f = 0.005(1+1.5*((l-0.6)**2))
        e = (1/((1+0.12*V*V*0.003*0.003)(1+(0.142+(f*AR[z]*(10*t/c)**0.33)
            +(0.1/(4+AR[z])**0.8))
        if z <= 5:                              # line 33 #
                                     z +=1
        else :
                                     break

   n+=1
```

OUTPUT:

```
  File "<ipython-input-49-d7d52927efb2>", line 33
    if z <= 5:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is a code which should tell me whether my aircraft will takeoff or not (on the input of a weight)
I cannot seem to understand the reason why is this syntax invalid ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in the code you provided. I tried to clean it up as best as I could. The following does not cause an error by default. This does *not* mean that the code does what it is supposed to do. You should still check that.

Your lists like CL and CD do not contain enough elements for most cases which will cause `IndexError: list index out of range`. You should extend those lists or use a different kind of logic to make sure this does not happen.

```
W = int(input('Enter weight:'))

b = [1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.0]
AR = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
T = [
    50.99238, 50.05062, 49.07943, 48.05919, 47.00952, 45.92061, 44.79246,
    43.62507, 42.42825, 41.18238, 39.90708, 38.60235, 37.24857, 35.86536,
    34.4331, 32.97141, 31.48029, 29.94012, 28.37052, 26.76168, 25.1136
]
CL = [1.0]
CD = [0.5]
clmax = 2
n = 0
z = 0
while b[n] < 2.1:

    while AR[z] < 5.1:
        cl = CL[n]
        cd = CD[z]
        s = ((b[n]*b[n])/AR[z])                                
        V = ((2*W*9.81)/(1.2*s*clmax) ** 0.5)*1.1
        vlof = V/1.41
        Vlof = round(vlof)
        D = 0.5*cd*1.2*Vlof*Vlof*s
        L = 0.5*cl*1.2*Vlof*Vlof*s
        # O.O5 -> 0.05*: you used the letter 'O' instead of '0' (zero). also
        # you always have to use * if you want to multiply something. you
        # cannot leave it out.
        a = (9.81/W)*(T[Vlof]-D-0.05*(W-L))
        Sg = (V*V)/(2*a)
        if Sg <= 30:
            print('IT WILL TAKEOFF')
        else:
            print('It will NOT takeoff')
        # t/c -> t_c: you cannot use special characters when defining
        # variables. best stick to lower- and upper-case letters,
        # the underscore and numbers.
        t_c = int(input('t/c ratio is:'))
        l = int(input('Taper ratio is:'))
        # a whole lot of closing parentheses and '*' were missing here. also
        # cleaned up the formatting
        f = 0.005*(1+1.5*((l-0.6)**2))
        e = (
            1 / (
                (1+0.12*V*V*0.003*0.003)*(
                    1 + (
                        0.142+(f*AR[z]*(10*t_c)**0.33)
                        + (0.1/(4+AR[z])**0.8)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        # in Python, space has meaning. it determines which part of the code
        # is executed at which level in the routine. you cannot chose it 
        # arbitrarily.
        if z <= 5:
            z += 1
        else:
            break
    n += 1
```

Comment: Great, I'll keep this mind!! I appreciate your help